# Does the entire scene get drawn on screen?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Ok so i'm building a game and just using the WebPlayer.

It plays just fine for me and others with no performance issues.

I loaded it to an iPhone 5 to see how it would handle performance and it's far from acceptable. Likely due to the nature of it and all of the objects and effects being drawn.

Is the entire scene loaded at once or are the items that are out of range only drawn when the camera is in that area?

Here is the game

http://burningfistentertainment.com/3D/DevilsNote/index.html

Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the entire scene loaded at once

Yes it is. When you load a scene everything contained is loaded into memory. Eventually try to split the scene.

> are the items that are out of range only drawn when the camera is in
>   that area

Each active `GameObject` inside **camera frustum** with a `Renderer` component will be rendered. Always animated [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Animator.html) components can affect performances even if not rendered.

> I loaded it to an iPhone 5 to see how it would handle performance and
>   it's far from acceptable. Likely due to the nature of it and all of
>   the objects and effects being drawn.

It's hard to say what could be the bottleneck without knowing more about your code. If you think the problem is GPU related, here's
some tips for mobile:

- **reduce draw-calls** (it depends on the device, I'd say no more than 50-70) => reduce materials count(use **atlas**), mark static objects as static (this way can be **static batched**),...
- **limit overdraw**: reduce size and number of transparent objects (what about rain? how do you implemented it?)
- consider using **occlusion culling** (probably not a problem in your game, but if the depth complexity increases it could save you a lot of GPU workload)